# Problema al actualizar Debian edu

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, redes, vsftp

tengo un problema al instalar el servicio ftp en debian edu además de que no me deja actualizar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el mensaje que me da si instalo el servicio ftp es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

también me he medito en las sources.list  lo he modificado pero igual sigue dándome fallo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola bienvenid@ a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

solo necesitas tener estos 4 y resolverás el problema. Al parecer el repositorio bullseye no sirve actualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]